# Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy when a cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm currently working on an app with a UITableViewController. The idea is that when a cell is tapped on, an info page will pop up showing some information about it. So when tapped on, I attempt to present another ViewController in another class. However, the warning shows up and I'm not sure why.

I've tried looking at questions similar to mine on Stackoverflow and other websites, but they don't make much sense to me. Can anyone explain the problem behind this warning and how to fix it?

Some of my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("showing item info")
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    currentInfo = (cell?.textLabel?.text)!
    currentDes = descriptions[indexPath.row]
    currentBool = itemBools[indexPath.row]
    currentIndexPath = indexPath
    showInfo()
}


func showInfo() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowInfoViewController") as! ShowInfoViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Warning message is:

```
Attempt to present <Things_to_Do.ShowInfoViewController: 0x100b2fe20> on <Things_to_Do.TableViewController: 0x100b05eb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The problem was cause I had created a segue on the storyboard, connecting a table cell to the new ViewController. By writing code to present the same ViewController, XCode got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add presentation style

**Swift 2**

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to present the ViewController from a class which is not there in the window hierarchy. You need to check `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` whether the self in this line is a ViewController which is added to the window hierarchy before you execute that line.